# Python with threads

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I am trying to create threads with python and it gives me some errors:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)    self.run()
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run

    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

And this is the class that creates the threads:

```
import time
import threading

import eel

import backend.flowers as flower
import backend.python_video_stream.client as camera
import backend.senzori as senzori
import backend.senzori.temperature.temperature as temp

eel.init('frontend')

flower_thread = threading.Thread(target=flower)
flower_thread.start()


# for temperature
Temperature_thread = threading.Thread(target=temp)
Temperature_thread.start()

# for cameras
# camera_thread = threading.Thread(target=camera.client)

eel.start('View.html')
```

The fist thread is working apparently, but still give me errors. What should I do in this situation?

Comment: The error indicates that "flower" and "temp" are modules, not functions.

Comment: You must write functions which should be executed in the threads and give these functions as "target" argument when creating the thread objects.

Comment: @MichaelButscher ok I managed to create a funciton for each and I call them for example: flower_thread = threading.Thread(target=flower.flowes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, `flower` and `temp` are modules. The `target` parameter of `Thread` expects a `Callable` object, typically a function.

For example:

```
flower_thread = threading.Thread(target=flower.flowes)
```